# Check if there exists a cycle containing a certain edge in a graph where the sum of edge values is greater than 0

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let us say that we have an undirected graph, where each edge has a real number value. Let us define the "sum" of a cycle as the sum of the values of each edge in that cycle.

Is there a reasonably fast way to check if there exists a cycle within the graph containing a certain edge E where the sum is greater than/smaller than 0? Right now my (extremely crude and horribly inefficient) solution is to check for every cycle the edge is in.

The algorithm does not need to find an exact cycle, it only needs to check for existence of such a cycle.

Comment: Can there be negative cycles not involving that edge?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I'm not sure what you mean by that. Any valid cycle can be positive, zero, or negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you allow only *simple* cycles, no, there is no efficient algorithm to do so, as it will let us solve [Hamiltonian Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) efficiently. (In other words, this problem is [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness)).

Reduction:

(We will use a variant of your problem where we find if there is such *simple* cycle with weight greater/equals zero).

Given a graph `G=(V,E)`, build a new graph:

```
G' = (V',E')
V' = V U {s,t}
E' = E U { (s,v), (v,t), (s,t) }
And add weights to the graph:
w(s,t) = -|V'| + 1
w(u,v) = 1    for u!=s and v!= t
```

Intuitively, we add a "source" and "target" nodes, connect them to all other nodes, and make the two nodes connected with negative weight of all paths.

The reduction is sending `(G', (s,t))` to the new algorithm.

Now, if the original graph has hamiltonian path `v1->v2->...->vn`, then the new graph has a cycle `s->v1->v2->...->vn->t->s`, which sums to 0, and is a simple cycle.

If there is a simple cycle in `G'` that uses `(s,t)`, and sums to any number greater than 0, then it means total weights of all other edges except `(s,t)` used is at least `|V'|-1`.
From the construction, that means there are exactly `|V'|` nodes in this cycle, which is the entire graph, so we know the cycle is: `s->t->v1->v2->...->vn->s`, and since this is simple, `v1,v2,...,vn` are all the nodes in the original `V`, which means there is a Hamiltonian Path `v1->v2->...->vn`.

**Conclusion**: We have shown a polynomial time reduction from Hamiltionian Path to your problem, and since HP is NP-Hard, this problem also is.